# Style background of Cell in EditMode in RadGridView

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, styles, radgridview

I want to style a cell in a RadGridView so whenever the cell turns into edit mode the backgroundcolor is e.g. yellow.

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="Name" SelectionUnit="Cell">
  <telerik:RadGridView.Resources>
       <Style  TargetType="telerik:GridViewCell">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsInEditMode" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
  </telerik:RadGridView.Resources>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

This doesn't do anything.

Comment: Are you sure the background isn't hidden by the element in the cell?  Meaning, if a cell displays a textbox while in edit mode, is it expanding to all borders of the cell and hiding whats beneath it?

Comment: It is hidden. When I doubleclick a cell the cell turns to the white textbox and the number in it is marked blue. Is there a way to change the white colour?

Comment: `<TextBox Background="Yellow"/>`

Comment: thanks!! that helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the `GridViewCell`, when editable, displays a `TextBox` that consumes the entire space the `GridViewCell` has available; so setting the background of the `GridViewCell` does nothing, because you can't see the background of the `GridViewCell`.  The solution is to change the background of the control that is displayed while the `GridViewCell` is editable, thus we need to change the `Background` of the `TextBox`.

In the `RadGridView` do the following:

```
<telerik:RadGridView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightYellow"/>
        </Style>
</telerik:RadGridView.Resources>
```

It changes the background color of each selected-to-edit Cell to `LightYellow`.

Comment: Without just posting the answer add some more description.
It'll help the person who ask the question to understand the solution you purposed.